# DocuSign API - Is there a programmatic way to use Data Validation for Text Fields?

Tags: docusignapi

DocuSign API - Is there a programmatic way to use Data Validation for Text Fields  as described [here](https://www.docusign.com/DocuSignHelp/Content/data-validation.htm#Custom) ?

I would like to specify on a [com.docusign.esign.model.Text](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client) field that it should accept only a valid format SSN, ZIP or Email.

Has anyone found a way to do that without regex?

Comment: Do you want to do all the three validations on one Text field or separate text fields?

Comment: I want one validation per Text field - I will have 3 separate text fields: one for SSN, one for ZIP and one for Email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use the Email/SSN/Zip tabs provided in the [SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client)

See the API Recipe [here](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-rest-recipes/blob/master/core_recipes/CoreRecipes.java) and add the following tab creation logic.

Here is a sample code

```java
 Tabs tabs = new Tabs();

 //SSN Tabs
 Ssn ssn = new Ssn();
 ssn.setDocumentId("1");
 ssn.setPageNumber("1");
 ssn.setRecipientId("1");
 ssn.setXPosition("100");
 ssn.setYPosition("100");

 List<Ssn> ssnTabs = new ArrayList<Ssn>();      
 ssnTabs.add(ssn);
 tabs.setSsnTabs(ssnTabs);


 //Zip Tabs
 Zip zip = new Zip();
 zip.setDocumentId("1");
 zip.setPageNumber("1");
 zip.setRecipientId("1");
 zip.setXPosition("200");
 zip.setYPosition("100");

 List<Zip> zipTabs = new ArrayList<Zip>();      
 zipTabs.add(zip);
 tabs.setZipTabs(zipTabs);


 //Email Tabs
 Email email = new Email();
 email.setDocumentId("1");
 email.setPageNumber("1");
 email.setRecipientId("1");
 email.setXPosition("300");
 email.setYPosition("100");

 List<Email> emailTabs = new ArrayList<Email>();      
 emailTabs.add(email);
 tabs.setEmailTabs(emailTabs);

 Signer signer = new Signer();
 signer.setEmail(signerEmail);
 signer.setName(signerName);
 signer.setRecipientId("1"); 
 signer.setTabs(tabs);
```